# How can I redirect URL where parameters have not value via .htaccess to 404 page?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I have got an order to make redirection on site to 404 page, if reaquest parameter not specified value, i.e. "/?qwerty" (where "qwerty" means invalid parameter, without '=' and any value) must be redirected. I have wrote .htaccess file (site works with Joomla). You can see the fragment below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http:// [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=(\.\.//?)+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=/([a-z0-9_.]//?)+ [OR]
#Next string redirects all of requests with parameters
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [R=404,L]
```

But now site can't process any request with parameter. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect to `404` if the query value parameter is missing, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^querty$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^querty=$

RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404,L]
```

This will redirect `example.com/?querty` **or** `example.com/?querty=`  **to** `/404` .

Comment: Thank you, but i meant it must redirect any parameter name. You gave me idea, the code below works as I want:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404,L]`